# Azure mobile apps: can't send push notifications from my nodeJS back-end

Tags: node.js, azure, push-notification

First, I should clarify that I'm only using free modules and service plans on the Azure side, using a Bizspark subscription.

I'm currently trying to run the app in the following tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push

Everything works on the client side, items are correctly sent and stored in the database. However, I can't make the NodeJS server send push notifications to devices.
I basically copy and pasted the code on the tutorial for the nodeJS back-end on the tutorial, redeployed/restarted the server, but not a single push notification is sent.

I tried to see where in the code something was wrong, so I went and used some logger.info here and there. I then found out that context.push is undefined.

However, I did connect the mobile app to the notification hub in the "push" category in the menu of my mobile-app in Azure (it does appear connected).

[Push page on my mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4kQ.png)

Google cloud messaging is also correctly configured, I get the push notification for the successful registration when I start the app.

What am I missing? Is it because I'm using free plans (notification hub, database, service plan)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could test sending notifications via the Azure portal, to do this, please see steps below.

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your notification hub.
2. Click on **Test Send** under the **SUPPORT + TROUBLESHOOTING** menu.
3. Select the platform you used, then fill payload message and click **Send** button.

[image]

Almost immediately (but in reality, it could be a few minutes because of PNS delays), you will see the push notification alert on your application.

For node.js backend on Azure mobile apps, you could use the following lines of code to send a push notification to all registered clients.

```
var payload = {
  data: {
    message: 'Hello!'
  }
};
notificationHubService.gcm.send(null, payload, function(error){
  if(!error){
    //notification sent
  }
});
```

For more info, please check out [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial.md).

Answer (score 0):

I did try the test send a few times and it worked perfectly, hence why  I couldn't understand how it couldn't work. I couldn't use the exact same code @aaron-chen-msft posted as I use the basic back-end nodeJS server on Azure (the quickstart one, so I would need to install the "azure" npm package), but I added the following string to my mobile app settings (application settings tab) on azure:

key : MS_NotificationHubName    value : MyNotificationHubName (here, Poke-Forgh)

Context.push was then not undefined, but the notifications weren't sent, so I got inspired by @aaron-chen-msft's code and I edited the nodeJS code to specifically send notifications to GCM:

```
 context.push.gcm.send(null, payload, function (error) { ... }
```

And it finally worked. Thanks!